# Typescript: An interface with optional properties is not assignable to a type with the same but required properties

Tags: typescript

Here is what i wanna do:

```typescript
const assign = <T extends U, U>(original: T, changes: U) =>
  <T>Object.assign({}, original, changes);

interface IFoo {
  bar: number,
  baz?: string,
  quux?: boolean,
}   

let foo = <IFoo>{ bar: 42, baz: 'hello' };

assign(foo, { baz: 'world' }); //Compilation Error:
```

I just wanna implement a type safe `assign`. but the compiler throws the error:

> Argument of type 'IFoo' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ baz: string; }'.
>     Property 'baz' is optional in type 'IFoo' but required in type '{ baz: string; }'.

The properties of `changes` type should always be a strict subset of `original` type, this kind of assignment should be totally logical, I think.

How do I get around it, appeasing the scrupulous compiler without sacrificing the type safety of the `changes` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Your generics are wrong, if I understand you right.

It should be:

```
const assign = <T>(original: T, changes: T) => <T> Object.assign({}, original, changes);

interface IFoo {
    bar?: number;
    baz?: string;
    quux?: boolean;
}   

let foo = <IFoo> { bar: 42, baz: 'hello' };

assign(foo, { baz: 'world' });
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20assign%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(original%3A%20T%2C%20changes%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%3CT%3E%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20original%2C%20changes)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20bar%3F%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20baz%3F%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20quux%3F%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%7D%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20%3CIFoo%3E%20%7B%20bar%3A%2042%2C%20baz%3A%20'hello'%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aassign(foo%2C%20%7B%20baz%3A%20'world'%20%7D)%3B))

Both your `original` and `changes` are of the same type, just that each of them has different properties defined in the interface (based on your example of course).
You do not have two different types which one extend the other, so `<T extends U, U>` is wrong.

Also, since you want to be able to only have subset of the properties in the interface then you must make them all optional, otherwise you'll get compilation errors.

---

#### Edit

Based on your comment, this might work for you:

```
const assign = <T extends U, U>(original: T, changes: U) => <T> Object.assign({}, original, changes);

interface FooOptional {
    baz?: string;
    quux?: boolean;
}

interface FooMandatory extends FooOptional {
    bar: number;
}

let foo = { bar: 42, baz: 'hello' };

assign(foo, { baz: 'world' });
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20assign%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20U%2C%20U%3E(original%3A%20T%2C%20changes%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20%3CT%3E%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20original%2C%20changes)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FooOptional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20baz%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20quux%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FooMandatory%20extends%20FooOptional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%20bar%3A%2042%2C%20baz%3A%20'hello'%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aassign(foo%2C%20%7B%20baz%3A%20'world'%20%7D)%3B))

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I want. I want to define a type with some mandatory props which must be provided at the first place, and the rest  props could/should be assigned later by some related functions. The `changes` are supposed to be subset props changes, not the entire thing.
Also, an interface with all optional props doesn't make the error go away. Thanks though!

Comment: Ok, check my revised answer

Comment: Read your edit. Look, if you change the line `let foo = {bar:42,baz:'blah'}` to `let foo :FooMandatory = {bar: 42, baz:'blah'}` the type check won't work. So the problem I described stay unsolved :(

Comment: It does if you do: `assign(foo, { baz: 'world' } as FooOptional)`

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I just thought of it. It just a little bit  verbose. Anyway, It IS a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, the compiler isn't aware that `{ baz: 'world' }` is a `FooOptional` unless you tell it, so it doesn't agree that the type of `foo` extends it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `T extends U` in `assign`, since you are "only" interested in type checking of U

```
const assign = <T, U>(original: T, changes: U) => <T> Object.assign({}, original, changes);
```

U could be defined as

```
interface U {
     baz: string
}


let foo = <IFoo>{ bar: 42, baz: 'hello' };
let u: U = { baz: 'world' }
assign(foo, u);
```

Comment: Yes I do!  I have to specify that U is a subset of T, otherwise there will be no meaningful type safety enforced by this `assign` function, the generics parameters T, U would be pointless.

Comment: I know this will not be as automatic that you wished for (and I doubt it can be), but can't you specify the types at the time you assign e.g. `assign<IFoo,U>(foo, u)` ?

Comment: Think about it from the point of view of a user of the api written by me, he has to remember the names of all the base and derived interfaces, IMHO that is not ideal. `assign(func1(), func2())`

Comment: Fair enough. @NitzanTomer answer is probably better suited then, at the cost of relaxing the mandatory constraints on the base interface